# Call an Oracle store a procedure which doesn't return values using Doctrine2

Tags: oracle, symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to call a store procedure which doesn't return any data so I wouldn't need any kind of hydratation.

When I try to do this

```
 $rsm = new \Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping();            
 $query = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->createNativeQuery(
      "CALL SP_CARGA_LIQ(...)", $rsm );
 $query->getResult();
```

an exception occurrs with the following message:

Warning: oci_fetch_array(): ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute and fetch in /var/www/LiquidacionesWeb/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/OCI8/OCI8Statement.php line 217

Does anyone know how to solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case closing call in `BEGIN` `END` block helped. Meaning:

```
$query = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->createNativeQuery(
      "BEGIN SP_CARGA_LIQ(...); END;", $rsm );
```

One way or another it's seems to be rather Oracle's error, not Doctrine's

EDIT:
You can do it in more native way:

```
 $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection()->exec("BEGIN SP_CARGA_LIQ(...); END;");
```

Comment: I've tried what you suggest but it throws the exact same exception.

Comment: Is there a way to set parameters to that function ?

Comment: I've used

    $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection()->executeQuery( /*The query*/, 
        array( /*parameters*/ ) );

Internally it calls the function you comment. Thanks.